# What event would I use to intercept and handle all runtime errors in a webform page?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, webforms

What event would I use to intercept and handle all runtime errors in a webform page?

Also how would I know what exception was intercepted if I used the property e. ?

Thank you!!! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do it in a single page, you would override the `Page_Error` method, just like you do `Page_Load`.

If you want to do it for your entire application, and I think you might, you'll need to change your `Global.asax`:

```
    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

        //Handle your error as you wish
    }
```